# SED Replace character with '

Tags: sed, csh

Trying to put `'` before each line of text and `'` at the end of each line of text.

I have been using `sed 's/^/1/'` file.txt to replace to begging of each line and `sed 's/$/0/'` file.txt to replace the end of each line.

What I am trying to make work is `sed 's/^/'/'` and `sed 's/$/'/'`

This would format my file to make each line reach as a command, when applied to a separate script.

Comment: `sed "s/^/'/;s/$/'/#"`  -- just use double quotes.   The solitary dollarsign, I think, is fine unescaped, but maybe not all shells.

Comment: @stevesliva tried a few variations using double quotes but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo abc | sed "s/.*/'&'/"
```

Output:

```
'abc'
```

From `man sed`:

> The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which
> matched

Comment: Works, thank you. Can you break down the line I think I understand it but want to be clear about it, if you do not mind.

Comment: `.*` matches the complete line (pattern space). `sed` replaces this with `'` followed by pattern space followed by `'`.